# Reading a stock file (txt) and writing to a receipt file (txt)

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that reads a stock file and writes to an invoice file but after a few weeks of trying and searching for the answer I got stuck. Can someone please help? The code needs to be able to read a stock file with a  gtin code and write to a file in a receipt format. it also needs to calculate the total order cost and write it to the receipt as well as showing it in the python shell.

```
import csv  
import os   
import math 

gtin = []
stock_list = []
order_total = 0

with open("Stock.txt","r+") as stock:
stock_1 = csv.reader(stock, delimiter=',') #added {, delimiter=','} after stock
for row in stock_1:
    gtin.append(row[0])
    stock_list.append(row)
    print(stock.read())

    choice = False

order = input("What would you like order?")

if order in gtin:
    pass
else:
    print("This is not a valid product")

order_row = gtin.index(order)

item_price = int(stock_list[order_row][2]) / 100
order_total = item_price * order_quantity

print("Your current order total is equal to..." +order_total)
```

I expect the output to be,

```
What would you like to order? (gtin)
How much would you like to order? (Order_quantity)
This is your order total (Order_Total)
```

And the receipt external text file would show the item ordered, how much was ordered and the total cost.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Do you get an error (if so, post the complete traceback)? Is the output not what you expect (if so, post input, expected output and actual output)?

Comment: can you add some sample input and expected output?

Comment: I have added an expected output as well as links to my stock file and the actual output.